# How to make Header & Footer fixed all time?

Tags: javascript, ios, css, cordova, jquery-mobile

I want to make header & footer fixed all time in Phone Gap Application under iOS 
I use jQuery Mobile but when open keypad or select menu (any native) the header & footer become not fixed also I disable toggling,
Also when open native thing (keypad Or Select) the position of simpledialog2 not be centered any more.

This is HTML code for header & Footer

```
<div id="PageHeader" data-role="header" data-theme="f" data-position="fixed"></div>
<div id="PageFooter" data-role="footer" data-theme="f" data-position="fixed"></div>
```

This code JS for disable toggling in document ready

```
$("[data-role=header]").fixedtoolbar({ tapToggle: false });
$("[data-role=footer]").fixedtoolbar({ tapToggle: false });
```

If any one have this issues & trying to solve it, Please show me the way.

Best Regards.

Comment: @peterm : I have update the post with markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using position: fixed, you might find that there are things you can't overcome.  In the older days of phones, position: fixed wasn't even an option because they were afraid that hte fixed elements would cover up other UI elements on the small screen and make stuff inaccessible.  Of course, this was a stupid thought and everyone complained about hte lack of position: fixed.  Only in the last couple years have phones and other mobile devices begun to support position: fixed.  iOS actually has the best support of all but it didn't arrive until iOS 5.

I wouldn't be surprised if there are special conditions like the one you described with no work around.

Comment: WORKAROUND:  If you're using position: fixed, then temporarily change the elements ot position: absolute and reposition them with javascript.  Awkward.  I wouldn't recommend it unless you really have to do it.

Comment: in your opinion how to reposition it by JS,

Comment: I don't write javascript often enough to tell you how off the top of my head.  jQuery is the easiest way if you want simple easy-to-write code.  $(#div-to-position).css("position: absolute; top: 322; left: 473");   Replace #div-to-position with the id of the div you want to position adn replace 322 and 473 with the values for positions you want to apply.   You'll need to do a little more homework on how to fire jQuery events if you want to do it this way.  Make sure you're able to fire it when you need it to happen because it might require some goofy workaround.

Comment: By the way, make sure you hit the Accept Answer checkmark if you accept the answers I've given.  Its important to do this when using stackoverflow.  People don't want to answer if you don't ever accept answers.  Its necessary for reputation.

Comment: and one more thing, if you want to ask a question about doing this repositioning with javascript, go ahead and start a new question on it because its completely different from your original question.  You might get some other input.

Comment: I do it, and this the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039317/how-do-i-re-position-fixed-header-footer)