# how do i re-position fixed Header & Footer?

Tags: javascript, ios, css, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have got some issues when using fixed Header & Footer,
But some suggest on me to use Position: Absolute instead of Fixed
and re-position Header and footer when scroll using JavaScript Code,
Does any one know how to do this?
Or this issue faced him.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Best Regards.

Comment: Please think a bit more about whether you're providing enough information. When you say 'some' issues, what does that mean? Both position:absolute and position:fixed can position elements, only differnce is that absolute positioning uses the document as it's coordinate space, where as in fixed positioning, the viewport is the coordinate space. Explain your question a bit more

Comment: @Mutahhir : I said 'some' issues because I didn't want to till about it, if you want to help that would be great-full else Please don't miss with my question. We are professional Developer.

Comment: I don't mean to be messing with your question, just pointing out that if you provide more information, you might get an answer that solves your problem. Asking a long question isn't a problem as long as it explains your problem properly.

Comment: @Mutahhir : forgive me, I got it wrong way, thanks for explanation, But do you know the answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I could help you out, if I really knew what you were trying to ask. If the answer below solved your problem, great. If not, post a little bit more about the problem you're facing having 'fixed' header and footer. In the answer, what he's proposing is that you go with position: absolute and then write the same code in javascript that would've been free with position: fixed. If you're trying to make one of those widgets that animate into the view as after you scroll. That's another story and for that you *would* need position: absolute with some javascript on the 'scroll' event.

Comment: @Mutahhir : the answer below is a temp solution , and not working under iOS 5.

Comment: :) You seem pretty adamant about not explaining the problem. Sorry, can't help you out like that. I don't know what to solve here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahmed, I just came over here from the other thread we had been discussing.  Your question isn't clear enough for the other folks to answer.  Your question should include the fact that you need to trigger the javascript function to reposition on a specific event.

One way you could do this is this:
Change the elments to absolute position instead of fixed.  Don't use fixed at all.  Then make the javacript function for positioning elements fire every time the browser window scrolls or finishes scrolling.  By doing it this way, the elements will always be moved into view after user finishes scrolling.  They will actually pop into view which will look ugly.  To make them smoothly move into view, you'll have to extend it further by using css3 transistions OR interpolating the position gradually with javascript. On iOS5 and iOS6, you should be able to use css3 transitions just fine.  They would be VERY easy to implement.  CSS3 transitions make javascript controlled animations a piece of cake.

The hard part will be implementing the javascript to compute the element positions and then fire the event after the browser finishes scrolling.

Hopefully some other folks can chime in if I've got the right direction.

Vote me up, bro. :)

Answer (score 1):

See if the code below helps (notice how the margin adjustments use negative values that are half the size of the div that is being positioned):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>align</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#text_center {
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-left:-100px;
    margin-top:-20px;
}
#text_bottom {
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    bottom:1%;
    margin-left:-100px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="text_center">Text 1</div>
    <div id="text_bottom">Text 2</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is Ok,but if I add this div to your code, the page will scroll, after scroll the Text 2 not in the bottom, so we need javascript code re-position it. ` <div id="text_center">Text 1</div>
<div style="height:1000px;position:relative"></div>
    <div id="text_bottom">Text 2</div>`